# Как регистрировать приложения в OAuth 2.0 программным способом?

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, oauth2

Дело в том, что мне нужно работать с данными гугл аналитики чужих сайтов.
Для этого нужно регистрировать приложение в OAuth для получения client id. 
Как можно регистрировать приложения при помощи REST-запросов ? Может есть способ получить client id, отправив GET запрос c параметрами на url.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вам много раз получать `client_id`. 
Нужно только один раз получить `client_id` и `client_secret`. 
А уже потом запрашивать доступ к аналитике для многих сайтов.

Comment: Просто, когда регистрируешь, там вводятся сайт с js скриптом аналитики и сайт редиректа. Если использовать client_id одного OAuth2.0 клиента и при запросе токена указать другой сайт, он выдает, что сайт не найден в настройках для этого client_id

Comment: Это сайт редирект. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js посмотрите на пример. Вам нужно что бы пользователь перешел на вашу страничку и дал вам права на доступ к GA

Comment: Нет нет, вы, кажется, не поняли, мне нужно, чтобы пользователи заходили, вводили данные, а я скриптом создавал сразу акк с client_id, redirect_utl и url сайта с js скриптом аналитики)

Comment: Правильно я вас понял, просто хотел показать правильно сделать. А то что вы хотите, то для этого API нет. И вам придется это парсить. Если хотите могу сказать как в теории нужно сделать. через API analytics. Я уже сталкивался с похожей задачей

Comment: Да, пожалуйста. Очень буду благодарен :)

Comment: Если коротко. то нужно что бы использовать не пароль и логин. а давать пользователю пройти через oauth2 и получить от них токен для управление их аккаунтом. Ну или получите для себя токен и используйте его. Потом для вас пригодится этот [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/devguide?hl=ru). Прочитайте 4 пункт. Вроде все.

Comment: Ооо, похоже это и правда то, что нужно. Мне, видимо, нужно было создавать accountTicket. Спасибо вам огромное) Я уже думал, что застрял насовсем ахах